# Checkedin a New Folder to the Solution , But when Changeset is Downloaded it wont show in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, tfs

Added a New Folder(with a User Control and a WPF Window) and my friend checkedin. So I downloaded that changeset via TFS , but it wont show the Newly added folder in the solution explorer. But it will show that folder in the local location where the solution exists.

So , is there anyway I can add back the folder to the Solution ?

is this normal ?

Comment: include the content of folder to your .csproj then it will show in solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the folder in the Windows Explorer and not in Solution Explorer you can click on the "Show all Files" button in top of the Solutions Explorer and add the folder in your solution.

If you just downloaded the project from the TFS and the folder is not visible, then may be your friend did not committed the .csproj file. Please check this with him.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the sln file wasn't checked in with the changeset. Get your friend to check it in.